# Как правильно задать коннект к БД

Tags: java

Создаю web-приложение на Spring MVC + Hipernate + MySQL.

Выгрузка отчетов будет. Есть база, но в виде СЕРВЕР и имя БД.
То есть в инете везде примеры такого типа

```
jdbc.databaseurl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/babobka
```

Нет у меня хоста и порта. Как можно использовать имя сервера и имя БД?
пробовал

```
jdbc.databaseurl=jdbc:mysql:СЕРВЕР/БД.
```

Не подключился.

Мне выдали вот такие данные: Microsoft SQL Server Instance: SRV-SQL-SERVER\SEVREPORT База данных: srv-sev-report

Comment: вы знаете на каком хосте расположен ваш сервер? откуда вы получаете имя сервера и имя БД?

Comment: да, я через пинг пробил хост, а вот порт не знаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта строчка

```
jdbc.databaseurl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/babobka
```

означает, что

- **localhost** - это имя хоста
- **3306** - номер порта. 3306 - это порт на котором MySql сервер слушает  по умолчанию
- **babobka** - имя базы

Так как у вас не MySql, а MS Sql, то строчка должна выглядеть так

```
jdbc.databaseurl=jdbc:sqlserver://SRV-SQL-SERVER:SEVREPORT;databaseName=srv-sev-report
```

Comment: Мне выдали вот такие данные: Microsoft SQL Server Instance: SRV-SQL-SERVER\SEVREPORT База данных: srv-sev-report

Comment: ошибка сейчас вот такая : ERROR: org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
WARN : org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Could not obtain connection metadata
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Comment: Я даже внимание не обратил что это разные вещи, получается и зависимости другие уже будут и настройка jdbc с драйверами

Comment: если вы правильно использовали фреймворк, то изменения будут минимальными

Comment: вроде правильно. теперь ошибка  Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver]. Буду дальше капать, спасибо :)

Comment: тепер такая ошибка (

Comment: ERROR: org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - The TCP/IP connection to the host srv-sql-server, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: no further information. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
WARN : org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Could not obtain connection metadata com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: